# JS dispatchEvent(textEvent) places text broken

Tags: javascript, facebook-messenger, messenger

## I have problem how to solve this issue:

### Problem:

Quick Reply which contain emoji send only last emoji

### Steps to reproduce:

- Try quick reply message with text `text ❤️ text` and only  is sent
- Try quick reply message with text `text ❤️ text` and only `❤️` is sent
- ...

It is this issue: https://github.com/hrubymar10/goofy_swift/issues/9

And so far I found that Swift part 'send' JS whole message right so for `text ❤️ text` JS really has `text ❤️ text` in its variable. JS handle it using this code:

```js
function replyToNotification(userid, answer) {
    document.querySelector(ID(userid) + ' a').click();
    setTimeout(function() {
        var textEvent = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
        textEvent.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, null, answer, 9, "en-US");
        document.querySelector(TEXT_BOX).dispatchEvent(textEvent);
        ignoreNotification = true;
        __triggerKeyboardEvent(document.querySelector(TEXT_BOX), 13, true);
    }, 50);
}
```

as I said before, var `answer` holds text with emojis without problem. But then it reaches this (I replaced `TEXT_BOX`:

`document.querySelector('._5rpu').dispatchEvent(textEvent);`

and message placed it message field is broken as it is described at the beggining...

This is the problematic line:
https://github.com/hrubymar10/goofy_swift/blob/84c482e99d3752e01fac020fc5c037dd0eaf834d/server/src/fb.js#L302

Comment: If you have identified a bug in the project code, you should open an issue in the project's github repo.

Comment: I did. It is this issue: https://github.com/hrubymar10/goofy_swift/issues/9

Problem is, that I have to fix it as owner of this project but I really don't know how to do that...

Comment: One issue to look at is that you are using document.createEvent and initCustomEvent, which is deprecated. According to MDN, you should use event constructors instead:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent